# How to find the lowest ID in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to find the lowest customer id in the array and increase it by 1.

So I need the for cycle to search for the biggest id (0 by default) and increase by 1 every time ( create a new object of the customer class.

I really don't know how to implement the "i" value in order to make the cycle search for the id...

My model:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
   public int IDCustomer {get; set;}
   public string LastNameCustomer {get; set;}
   public string FirstNameCustomer {get; set;}
   public string AdressCustomer {get; set;}
}
```

My algorithm attempt:

```
CustomerModel[] MemoryCustomers = new CustomerModel[9];
OrderModel[] MemoryOrders = new OrderModel[9];

public string CreateCustomer(CustomerModel model)
{
    CustomerModel NewCustomer = new CustomerModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         //What to put here        
    }
}
```

Comment: Stepping back, why are you doing this? It is an anti-pattern to assign ids by the max + 1 pattern.

Comment: That's a very bad idea - it's *very* easy to generate duplicate IDs this way, simply by deleting some entries. If the code is called from multiple threads, clients or even requests in a web app you'll also end up with duplicate values

Comment: I'd recommend you to calculate the ID based on the properties of each new entry.

Comment: That's gonna be a form-based application, wich does not depends on any db. Will be updated in future, i just need for the moment to let the method create an object of the customer class, search for the MaxValue id, increase by 1 the object's id and put it in the array.

Comment: Why do you need a numeric ID at all? What will it be used for? Can you talk us through why you don't want to use a GUID instead?

Comment: I need a numeric ID because i need incremental ID, in order easily search a customer via ID, GUID generates complicated randomic and unique ID wich is hard to be searched from a textbox.

Comment: You mean you let the user search for customer Id's in the application by entering them in a textbox? Perhaps using a unique customer name would be better?

Comment: Of course, but since the application should (hypothetically, since this is only practice) used by a seller(?), the user should be able to search from the ID since to this ID will be linked the Customer relative orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that.

You should instead try to get the *next id* for a customer from some external provider. If you're using a database system, that can generate indices for you - you just need to define a counter or ID-generator or some such thing in the DBMS. How that is done depends on which DB you are using.

Otherwise, you could create your own method that you can call each time you need a new id; something like:

```
newCustomer.IDCustomer = GetNextId();
```

If doing that, make sure the method can never return any ID more than once, and you should be safe. There are several ways to do this; one is to constantly increase a number. Another is to use an UUID or GUID:

```
 var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() // Generate a universally unique ID-string
```

The latter is especially useful if you want ID's that appear random, so that knowing one or two ID's won't make it easy to guess others (a common security problem / weakness in many apps).

---

**Update:**

Ok, ok: If you really want to simply get the next available ID as an int, based on existing int's, then try this:

```
private int GetNextId(){

    // Create a list for easy handling with LINQ:
    List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel)(MemoryCustomers);

    // Select only ids, and only the highest:
    int highestExistingId = customers 
                             .Select(cust => cust.IDCustomer)
                             .Max();

    return highestExistingId + 1;
}
```

If I've understood your question correctly now after re-reading it, I believe you want to update the lowest ID in your array, and replace it with a new customer,with the new ID - is that correct?

If so, try:

```
List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel)(MemoryCustomers);
var lowestId = customers.Select(cust => cust.IDCustomer).Min();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Identify the customer with that lowest id...
    if(MemoryCustomers[i].IDCustomer == lowestId)
    {
         // ... replace him with the new one:
         MemoryCustomers[i] = NewCustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: The application should run without any form of DB, so i don't actually want to use an external provider (SQL, Oracle). I want the app to be able to be updated apart from DBs.

Comment: @paranoidcoder Ok, I think I misunderstood part of your question earlier. I still stand by what I stated above in general, but I've changed my answer to include some code you can play around and experiment with, and which should help you (assuming I've understood you correctly now...).

Answer (score 2):

it is not a good practice to do that, you can use "SQL identity" if dealing with database.
or you can use type GUID to generate unique identifier for each customer.

Comment: That's true, but i need to create a application wich does not depends on a certain DB, i need the application to create an object and put it in an unspecified DB, could be in future Oracle,SQL, etc. Obviously with the right adjustments.

Comment: Then go with GUID, that the application can generate and it is unique.

Comment: most databases have identity feature with different names, it's not a new feature or something related to MSSQL only. 
but you have also the other option, you can go with GUID it's a good option for unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are searching for but it should work more consistent.

Add something like this to your Customer-Class:

```
private static int last_gen_id = -1;
public static int Gen_ID {
    get {
        last_gen_id++;
        return last_gen_id;
    }
}
```

And for every id, you want to generate, you just call `Customer.Gen_ID` and you got yourself a unique id. This will not work with threading, so be warned ;)